# Algorithm recommendation for string classification

Tags: algorithms

I have numerous (hundreds to low-thousands) of pre-classified short strings of text, each string is just a few words long, some just a single word.

The strings have been divided into a few dozen different categories, the number of strings in each category is quite variable - some categories have just a single string in them and some have hundreds.  I am looking for a good algorithm to help match new strings to one of the categories.

My only previous experience with this type of problem was using a Naive Bayesian Classifier, but given the 'unbalanced' nature of the data I'm not sure it would be the best fit in this case (perhaps I'm wrong?). I'm looking for something that is relatively easy to implement myself - this is partly a learning exercise, so I would prefer recommendations that don't involve just plugging in a library.

Comment: What criteria do you use to put strings into each bucket? Is it a property of the string, or is it arbitrary (e.g. matching movie titles to genres)?

Comment: Is the classification based on the literal meaning of the words? If so, would it make sense to pull in a thesaurus from a dictionary so that synonyms will be classified in similar ways?

Comment: @Snowman I would like to classify the strings purely according to their content, most of the strings within a given bucket contain one or more common words

Comment: @codebox you could certainly use some sort of machine learning, even something primitive like Bayes. I have a feeling that this application, like most, has some type of _a priori_ knowledge of the classification that would help quite a bit.

Comment: You can watch some of the lecture videos from [Coursera - Natural Language Processing](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture), without registration.

Comment: So the classification system is arbitrary? You want to sort new strings "purely according to their content". 

In that case, just to spell it out, you want an algorithm that can analyze a classification system and determine the pattern that a number of strings share. This could be anything from "number of vowels" to "English/german/leetspeak" to "offensiveness".  And then categorize new strings. Whoa.